# Unable to create Genymotion Virtual Device : HTTP Status 504

Tags: genymotion

I firstly downloaded and installed Genymotion in addition to virtual box and c++ 2008.

However, I was unable to create a virtual device and I got an error message as below.

Unable to create virtual device:
Server returned HTTP Status 504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem happens when you are connecting from a specific country that does not in list of genymotion cooperate.
for fixing this problem try to connect with a vpn,and then download your phone in genymotion...
when download is complete disconnect vpn to genymotion can deploy your custom phone
hope this help.